# Python: How to get intervals by points

Tags: python

I have a list of points:

```
p = [0.03, 0.05, 0.3, 0.7]
```

How to generate all intervals in distance [0;1]?

For example set of lists:

```
[0.0, 0.03]
[0.03, 0.05]
[0.05, 0.3]
[0.3, 0.7]
[0.7, 1.0]
```

And after I want check to which interval refer new input value. How to do it?

Comment: Please show what code you have written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this to generate the pairs:

```
p = [0.03, 0.05, 0.3, 0.7]
p2 = [0.0] + p + [1.0] 

for a in zip(p2,p2[1::]):
    print(list(a))
```

Gives:

```
[0.0, 0.03]
[0.03, 0.05]
[0.05, 0.3]
[0.3, 0.7]
[0.7, 1.0]
```

To check where new value belongs you can modify the code as:

```
new_val = 0.8

for a in zip(p2,p2[1::]):
    if a[0] <= new_val < a[1]:
        print("new_val is here:", a)
```

Gives:

```
new_val is here: (0.7, 1.0)
```